# displaiyng the data from my databse to my table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i need help displaying my data to my database and i keep getting these errors please someone help ill display the code and the errors

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class Form3 extends JInternalFrame {
private JButton button = new JButton("Button");
private JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(100,11));
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
Connection conn = null;


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Form3() {
    super();
    setBounds(-10, -10, 600, 450);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent argo) {
            try{
                String query1 = "SELECT * FROM csc3610_Connection.Oilform";
                java.sql.PreparedStatement pst1= conn.prepareStatement(query1);
                ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(button);
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jsp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    jsp.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    getContentPane().add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(6);
    table.setGridColor(Color.gray);
    }
   private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TablePanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

and here are the errors i get someone please help me. i have no idea what these errors mean and its making me made.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at guii.Form3$1.actionPerformed(Form3.java:39)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: How do you get you connection conn ? conn is null

Comment: `at guii.Form3$1.actionPerformed(Form3.java:39)` - The error message tells you which statement is causing the problem. So display the value of the variables used on that statement to determine which variable is null and then fix the problem. We can't debug the code for you.

Comment: that doesnt really help me..

Comment: `that doesnt really help me` - what doesn't help you? We are not mind readers. You have been given two good pieces of advice. Your previous question also dealt with a database. You got that code working so compare that code with this code to see what the difference is. We can't write the code for you, only point you in the right direction.

Comment: What im saying is i understand what u guys are saying but i have the same exact code in a different class and it works but not in this one for some reason. My database is fine i know that because my other class connects to it and gets the data

Comment: `i have the same exact code in a different class and it works` if the code was exact then it would work. But since it doesn't work we know the code is not exact that is why you need to learn how to do some basic debugging.  Based on the code provided the difference is obvious. Reread the first comment!